# What validation method is appropriate?

Tags: r, prediction, model-evaluation

My goal is to predict every game of the NCAA basketball tournament. I have data (team statistics for every game) from regular season and from tournaments (2003 - 2015). There are over 4000 games each season and only 63 games each tournament.

My features are the differences of the team statistics of team A and team B. Here is an example:

Team statistics of three games:

```
Team A
game    Result (label)  FGM     FGA     FGM3    
1       Won             27      58      8
2       Won             24      62      7
3       Lost            18      38      7
```

```
Team B
game    Result (label)  FGM     FGA     FGM3    
1       Lost            26      43      10
2       Won             24      48      11
3       Won             20      38      9
```

The cumulative means would be:

```
Team A
game    Result (label)  FGM     FGA     FGM3
1       Won             27      58      8
2       Won             25.5    60      7.5
3       Lost            23      52.7    7.3
```

```
Team B
game    Result (label)  FGM     FGA     FGM3    
1       Lost            26      43      10
2       Won             25      45.5    10.5
3       Won             23.3    43      10
```

Team A and Team B competed in game 3. My features are created by subtracting the cumulative means of game 2 and using the label of game 3.

```
FGM : 25.5 - 25   = 0.5
FGA : 60   - 45.5 = 14.5
FGM3: 7.5  - 10.5 = -3
```

My feature vector would be `F(0.5; 14.5; -3 | Lost)`. This is done for every game. Now to come back to my question. I believe cross-validation isn't appropriate. If I train my model on folds which contains games from the end of the season and test it on the fold which contains games from the beginning of the season will cause leakage. More specifically I can't use team statistics from future games to predict games from the past. What evaluation method can I use which gives me an good estimate of the performance of my model?

I appreciate any advice I can get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're on to the answer. Since your model will be used in predicting future games, the time component needs to be reflected in your validation and/or test sets. You can just split your data by time and use games from the end of the season to  validate. This will not give you a way to measure the variability in your model's performance like cross validation. If that is what you want, you can use a rolling cross validation with this method. Let's say you have 10 games in a season, you can build the model with first 4 games, predict and record the performance on the next 2 games(games 5-6), next rebuild the model on the first 5 games using the same model parameters from the first '4 game model' and predict the next 2 games( games 6-7) and so on. Then average the performance across all 3 game test sets to get a mean performance of your model.

Comment: Sometimes when time is an important component (e.g., increasing levels of competition or fatigues), having time in the model rather than splitting the data on time can be more helpful.

Comment: @FrankHarrell Yes I agree that is another approach you can take, an advantage in using your approach will be in small data set situations. However in evaluating the model's performance, I favor the time split since it aligns closely with the way the model will be used, which is using games played to predict future games in a season

Comment: @FelixNNelson Your first suggestion was my first approach which is I believe is called the hold-out validation. But that won't give me any measure on the variability of my model as you already mentioned. I like the idea of your second suggestion. What do you mean by rebuild the model using the same parameters? I was thinking building a model is the progress of estimating the parameters.

Comment: @FrankHarrell can you give me a reference to how to include the time component into the model or can you show me a simple way of doing it?

Comment: Calendar or elapsed time is just a covariate like any other, and you would use 100 repeats of 10-fold cross-validation or perhaps 300 optimism bootstrap resamples to validate the process to get overfitting-corrected estimates of predictive accuracy, ignoring time.

Comment: @DerTom what I mean is the same number of tuning parameters...for example if you use a support vector machine for example, you would use the same tuning parameter configuration , (eg. Cost parameter of 1 and sigma parameter = 0.05 with a rbf kernel). If you use a logistic reg, since there are no tuning parameters in this technique, you just fit logistic regressions with the same predictors/features at each stage.

Comment: @FrankHarrell if I understood you correctly I should include the date (which the game was played on) to the other variables and perform 10-fold cv 100 times but at each iteration the folds are randomly picked. In other words after every 10-fold cv the folds are changing.

Comment: Correct.  The bootstrap requires fewer model fits than that to give the same precision however.  Since you are modeling time the splits are random, ignoring time.

Comment: @FelixNNelson if I wanted to do feature selection using rolling cv do I have any limitations regarding the choice of filter methods (e. g. correlation, t-test or fisher-score)? Is PCA even allowed to use in that context?

Comment: @DerTom there are no limitations in the choice of filter methods you can use with rolling cv just like normal cv. You can use PCA in this case.

Comment: @FelixNNelson thank you again! can you explain why PCA is allowed in this case? or when should someone avoid PCA in the context of time?

Comment: @DerTom Don't mean to answer your question with a question but I'm wondering why you think PCA wouldn't be applicable... you can choose the components to include in your model before training any model(i.e. You can use it as a filtering method).

Comment: @FelixNNelson no problem. Well, I was wondering if the rotation causing by the PCA will change the time order of my cases (games). The whole point of using rolling cv is to preserve somewhat the time. Only past games should be in the training set and future games in the validation set. On the other hand I am only using PCA on the training set and use its rotation on the validation set. Even if PCA mix the time up it wouldn't matter since past games are still in the training set and future games in validation set, still preserving time. I might just answered my own question.

Comment: @DerTom yes, you just answered it, the rotation won't matter since you've reserved some future games for validation and testing purposes.