# How would I compare two models using different validation methods?

Tags: time-series, statistical-significance, cross-validation

I am using two different approaches in order to gauge the performance of a model:

1. The so called rolling cross-validation in order to preserve time in the data.
2. The ordinary k-fold cross validation. Time doesn't matter. Training set can have future events and test set can consist of past events.

Is there a way to test if one approach is better than the other? I am using the misclassification error as a metric.

**Edit**

This question is connected to this question:
[What validation method is appropriate?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/174205/what-validation-method-is-appropriate)

I am trying to predict the outcome of a basketball tournament. And I want to see if training a model considering time is (statistical significant) better than training a model without considering time. Or is it enough just to look at the misclassification error and say method A is slightly better but the differences aren't that big...

Comment: how about rigorously checking if your data is time invariant? this may subsequently select the best validation method

Comment: If you create a fixed holdout sample and generate predictions from both models for that fixed sample, wouldn't the comparison of predictive accuracy (PA) between the models provide a clue? In addition, since I'm not one to want to limit the comparison only to PA, I would also want to consider the stability of the parameters, the BICs, predictive power, "interestingness," novelty and/or the complexity of the resulting solutions, to name a few of the additional possible metrics worth comparing beyond just PA.

Comment: @DJohnson I wasn't sure if just looking at the accuracy will justify a decision. By stability do mean that I should check for each fold if the same features are selected, the same hyperparameters were chosen, etc.? if so what measures can I use to gauge this or do you have any reference I can look into?

Comment: I've usually evaluated *stability* in the context of a "random forest" type approach where, as the iterations evolve, one collects the coefficients produced for each feature and then compares the stability of those coefficients on the back end with a scale invariant metric of variability such as the coefficient of variation.

Comment: @DerTom I don't think there is a standard way to check this. Have you tried encoding time as one of the input feature and see if it is correlated with the output? This will give you a hint that time does indeed matter.

Comment: @mottalrd I have also done the third option - including time in data and use k-fold cv as suggested by Frank Harrell . With this approach I can compare the final model with the final model of approach nr 2 from above using the McNemar-Test. This might work...

Answer (score 1):

How to validate a validation model? I would think you would need treat the validation parameter as a training (meta)parameter, and optimize that based on test error from some withheld validation data set. That sub-validation mechanism must then have a standard way it effects training, but it seems you have that part handled.

Comment: I am not sure if this will solve my problem. But maybe I didnt understand your suggestion. I have edited my question to narrow down my problem.

Comment: Are you looking for guidance on how to use R to solve this? Or are you trying to understand how validation works so that you can understand how two validation strategies could be nested?

Comment: Its not about how to use r or how to nest two strategies. I have two final models: one created with approach A and the other with approach B. Now, I am asking if time have an influence on predicting games. I hope I made it clear now ;-)

Comment: You need to test them both using the same test. Ideally, this test would not involve any data used to train A and B. The one that performs better (ie lower error) wins. Hope that helps.

Comment: I am not sure if only looking at the classification error will justify a decision that e.g. method A is better (if both results are close). DJohnson suggests that I should also look at stability.

Comment: I edited my answer, as it mentioned some things that may not have been helpful. The type of stability I am aware of is unlikely to be applicable here, but I'm not sure I get what DJohnson mentioned.

Comment: I have decided to check whether the features selected in each fold are approx. the same, if hyper-parameters are approx. the same and if train error is much better than test error (overfitting). Knowing this and the classification error will give better insights if approach A is better than approach B.